# Finding the area of a circle tangentially inside a triangle

Tags: geometry

This is the problem:

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

Nevertheless, I'm not entirely sure whether the angle of the triangle formed by the line I've drawn is $90^0$. If it's so, then this must be true:

$$\begin{align}
3^2 &= 2(2+a)^2\\
a &= \frac32 \sqrt2 - 2
\end{align}$$

Could you tell me, if this is true, why is the angle $90^0$? Or if this isn't true, how do I solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any particular reason to assume that angle would be right.

Comment: You should be able to find some isosceles triangles if you give names to the center of the magenta circle, as well as the three points of tangency, though. Then the _radius_ of the magenta circle becomes fairly easy to find (no trig or square roots necessary) ...

Comment: @Troposphere I don't get it. So let's say the center is $O$,and the three points of tangency are $a,b,c$ respectively. Then? Sorry I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$AT = AP$

so $AT = 2$

Taking $B$ to be the origin of the Cartesian coordinate system, then

$A = (0, 3)$

The unit direction vector from A down the hypotenuse is $(\cos C, - \sin C) = (4/5, -3/5) $

$T = A + AT = A + 2 (4/5, -3/5) = (8/5, 9/5)$

$O = T + TO = (8/5, 9/5) + r (- 3/5, -4/5) = ( (8 - 3r)/5 , (9 - 4 r)/5 )$

$O$ is equidistance from $A$ and $B$ , hence $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$

thus,

$(9 - 4 r)/5 = 3/2$

$4 r = 3/2$

$r = 3/8$

Magenta Area = $\dfrac{ 9 \pi}{64} $

Comment: Genius! But it would be helpful if you tell how you get $4/5$ and $3/5$, even though after re-reading your answer I've figured out that it came from similarities of two triangles.